# re-running a script in a docker container

Tags: docker

I have created a docker image that includes some python code and a shell script that can execute it. It is going to process a bunch of images from the host system.

This command should create a new contaier and run it.

```
sudo docker run -v /host/folder:/container/folder opencv:latest bash /extract-embeddings.sh
```

At the end, the container exits. If I type the same command, then another container is created and exited at completion. But how is the correct usage of containers? Should I use restart, start or run (and then clean up exited containers after)? It just seems unnessary to create a new container each time.

I basically just want a docker image containing some code and 3-4 different commands I can execute whenever needed.

And the docker start command doesn't seem to accept "bash /extract-embeddings.sh" as parameters, instead things bash and extract-embeddings.sh are containers. So maybe I am misunderstanding the lifecycle of containers or the usage.

edit:

Got it to work with:

```
docker run -t -d --name opencv -v /host/folder:/container/folder
docker exec -it opencv bash /extract-embeddings.sh
```

Comment: The setup you describe (only Python packages, "running scripts", "host system files") sounds like a better match for a Python [virtual environment](https://packaging.python.org/tutorials/installing-packages/#creating-virtual-environments) than an isolation system like Docker.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can write the Dockerfile to create your docker image and keep the scripts into it-

**Dockerfile:**

```
FROM opencv:latest
COPY ./your-script /some_folder
```

**Create image:**

```
docker build -t my_image .
```

**Run your container:**

```
docker run -d --name my_container
```

**Run the script inside the container:**

```
docker exec -it <container_id_or_name> bash /some_folder/your-script
```

Comment: Thank you. I got it to work with "docker run -t -d --name opencv -v /host/folder:/container/folder"

Answer (score 1):

Build your own docker image that starts with opencv:latest and give the command you run as the entrypoint. Dockerfile could be like

```
FROM opencv:latest
CMD ["/bin/bash", "/extract-embeddings.sh"]
```

Use docker create to create a named container.

```
sudo docker create --name=processmyimage -v /host/folder:/container/folder myopencv:latest
```

Then use docker start each time you want to run it.

```
sudo docker start processmyimage
```

This works well if there is only one command you want to run. If there is more than one command, I would take the approach of building an image that runs unrelated command forever (like a tail -f < /dev/null). Then you can use 
    sudo docker exec -d /bin/bash < cmd-to-run >

for each command